# PUT and api uning NetHTTPRequest or anything else?

Tags: delphi

i would be very happy if someone could maybe help me with this.
I am trying to send a file (.csv) using NetHTTPRequest (or anything else what would work) and PUT and api. It has to be PUT because the server doesn't accept anything else.
I also need an api to log in.

In Powershell it would look like this:

The Client would be d329krpq (for example).

```
Invoke-WebRequest `
-UseBasicParsing `
-Uri https://example.com/d329krpq/filename.csv `
-Method PUT `
-InFile filename.csv `
-Headers @{'x-api-key'='lXViWTzFic9sM8Qqe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr'}
```

Thank you very much! Arne

Comment: By "help" you mean someone should write the entire code for you? You have not even attempted something yourself, let alone encountered examples?

Comment: Cross post: https://www.delphipraxis.net/211527-nethttprequest-put-und-api-new-post.html and https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/7552-nethttprequest-put-and-api/

Answer (score 1):

Before starting, you have to correctly set the URL of your server resource : it must end with the endpoint/resource name, not the destination of your uploaded file.
Like this example (the server is a PHP script) :
https://example.com/uploader.php

To send a "PUT" request in the `TNetHTTPRequest` or `TNetHTTPClient` or `THTTPClient` component, you can use any of its "Put" overloaded methods. There is a version of the "Put" method where you can specify the server URL, the path to your file on your local drive or storage, and other optional parameters for the response stream and request headers.
After processing the request, the function will return an instance of `IHTTPResponse` that you can access its `ContentStream` property to check the response of your server. Afterward, it is up to your server to retrieve the uploaded file from the request content.

To proceed, just drop a `TNetHTTPRequest` control from the palette on your form, and create a procedure to "Put" your file, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
begin
  NetHTTPRequest1.Put('https://example.com/uploader.php', 'C:\MyFile.csv');
end;
```

Or, if you want to create and destroy components on the fly without dropping anything on the form, you can proceed like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
var
  LHTTP: TNetHTTPClient;
begin
  LHTTP := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    LHTTP.Put('https://example.com/uploader.php', 'C:\MyFile.csv');
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to send multiple files, then you can use the overloaded function with the `TMultipartFormData` object. You can create a `TMultipartFormData` object and call its `AddFile` function to specify the name (for distinguishing the file the request), the path and content type of your file. And then you "put" the object, like this example :

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
var
  LHTTP: TNetHTTPClient;
  LFormData: TMultipartFormData;
begin
  LHTTP := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  LFormData := TMultipartFormData.Create();
  try
    LFormData.AddFile('File1', 'C:\MyFile.csv');
    LHTTP.Put('https://example.com/uploader.php', LFormData);
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
    LFormData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If your server does not handle Multipart form data, then you can check other solutions. We recommend using the REST Client library, where you can simply use the `TRESTRequest` `AddFile`. You only have to specify the name (to distinguish the file in the request's content), its path and its content type.

Drop the components `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest` and `TRESTResponse` on the form, and write your code.
Like in this example:

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
begin
  try
    try
      RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
      RESTRequest1.AddFile('File1', 'C:\MyFile.csv',  TRESTContentType.ctTEXT_CSV);
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
    except
      ShowMessage('Uploading failed');
    end;
  finally
    ShowMessage(RESTRequest1.Response.Content); // here you can see your server's response
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Would this solve anything? I do not have a sandbox this is why I am cautious:

Comment: How else could we help you?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help. Do I have to add a file (RESTRequest1.AddFile('File1', 'C:\MyFile.csv',  TRESTContentType.ctTEXT_CSV); if I already have the file declared in my client header? If yes, then which content type do I use to send a csv? At the moment the csv arrives as a txt? I would need a application/csv which I already declared in my header (Rest Debugger)?

Comment: Why are there 2 ContentType declarations? One in the RESTRequest.AddFile and one in the Header when I use the Rest Debugger? Is there an application/csv in the RESTRequest.AddFile command? I am confused... Thank you! Trying hard to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: In TRESTClient, you have to use the "AddFile" method because it is the only way to load the file's content in the request. Declaring the file name in the request's header won't upload it.

The content type in the header is for the whole request's content, it is mostly "MultiPart/Form-Data". While the content type in the "AddFile" method is only for that part (the file) of the request.

Comment: Unfortunately, TRESTClient has no "Application/CSV" content type. But, it is optional to define it, as the default value is "ctNone". It is up to your server to define what to do with the received file (you can even send a Word document with PDF as content type and your server still can handle that file as a Word document).

Comment: `After processing the request, the function will return an instance of IHTTPResponse` - do you know of an example of this which we can look at ?

Comment: TNetHttpClient will send an HTTP request to the specified URL by using its HTTP request methods (Get, Post, Put, Delete, ...), and will wait for the server to send a response. The TNetHttpClient will return, in the end, the HTTP response of the server as an instance of IHTTPResponse.

Comment: You can use IHTTPResponse's properties and methods to get the response's content (either as a stream or a string), metadata (date, last modified, ...) and status code (200, 403, 404, ...)

Comment: Here is a minimal example about using the "IHTTPResponse" resulted from "Get" function after downloading a file. This code will check the status code of the IHTTPResponse then copy its content's stream to a file stream (in case of success), otherwise it will raise an error :

Comment: procedure DownloadFile;
var
  LResponse: IHTTPResponse;
  LStream: TFileStream;
  LHttpClient: THTTPClient;
begin
  LHttpClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    LResponse := LHttpClient.Get('URL of the file');
    if LResponse.StatusCode = 200 then
    begin

Comment: LStream := TFileStream.Create('C:/FileName', fmCreate, fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
       try
          LStream.CopyFrom(LResponse.ContentStream, LResponse.ContentStream.Size);
       finally
         LStream.Free;
       end;
     else
       begin

Comment: raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot get distant file. Please contact us or retry later. HTTP %d - %s', [LResponse.StatusCode, LResponse.StatusText]);
        end;
    end;
  finally 
    LHttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;